# How to copy Fortnite onto another PC?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I have Fortnite installed on my friend's PC, and want to play on my own PC. I copied the Epic games folder to my PC. I clicked on Epic game launcher but nothing happens.

I'd like to avoid a 20 GB download by copying over the files if possible. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Copying the game files won't be enough to play the game. You'd have to buy it or borrow your friend's account (not recommended).

Comment: @Studoku i thought fortnite is free-to-play game...

Comment: Huh, so it is. In that case, what's stopping you downloading it from their site?

Comment: @Studoku, downloading again that 20++ gb... hell no...

Comment: Fair enough. Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This has worked for me when transferring it from laptop to my PC:

1. Download the Epic launcher yourself.
2. Install the Epic launcher **Example** C:Program Files\Epic Games (or some other path)
3. Attempt to install
4. Cancel the install and look for the folder with download files (usually in the epic games directory)
5. Delete the downloaded files there (keep folder intact).
6. Copy over the fortnite files you already have.The Epic Game directory should now look something like:

   - DirectXRedist
   - Fornite
   - Launcher
7. Close and reopen launcher, it now should say "Verify" rather than "Download".
8. Enjoy